# filtering of content in a form dynamically django

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-templates, django-views

view.py

```
def total_rent(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    venues = Venue.objects.all()
    places = Venue.objects.values_list('place', flat=True).distinct()
    context1 = ({'venues': venues, 'places': places})
    total = request.GET.get('venue')
    context1.update({'total': total})
    return render_to_response("test3.html", context1, context)
```

test3.html

```
<form action="" method="get">
    <select name="pl">
        <option selected="selected" disabled>---------</option>
        {% for place in places %}
            <option value="{{ place }}">{{ place }}</option>
        {% endfor%}
    </select>
    <input type="button" value="filter" />
    {% for venue in venues %}
        <input type="radio" name="venue" id="venue{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ venue.rent }}">
        <label for="venue{{ forloop.counter }}"></label>
        {{venue.venue_Name}}        
        {{ venue.place }}parking:{{ venue.parking_area }}
        Rs {{ venue.rent }}     
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit" value="service" />
</form>
```

I want to filter the venues when i select the place pressent in the droup down menue and button is pressed filter the content

Comment: There is a lot missing here. You will either need to write some javascript to fetch via ajax the venues when selecting a place, then update the venue options, or re-post the form when selecting a place, then reload the page with the right venues, OR, just do all the filtering on in javascript. Give one of those options a shot, then we can help you out with any bugs.

Comment: could you give some basic code to start with

Answer (score 0):

You have to write an ajax function to retrieve venues. call the ajax function jquery onchange of select tag of places.